how to put a custom close button in bootstrap modal
I'm working on a project where I need to create a Bootstrap modal with a close button positioned at the top right corner. While I've managed to position the button using CSS, it's not quite sticking to one spot. Despite applying absolute positioning, the button seems to move around inconsistently. I've tried troubleshooting the issue by adjusting the CSS properties and inspecting the elements in the browser's developer tools, but I haven't been able to find a solution.



/* POD Image Modal  */
#POD__Modal .modal-body {
  padding: 0px;
}

#POD__Modal .modal-header {
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

#POD__Modal #modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: -0.1rem;
  right: 0rem;
  z-index: 999999;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}
#POD__Modal .btn-close
{
  filter:  invert(1) grayscale(100%) brightness(300%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

#POD__Modal .modal-content {
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

#POD__Modal .modal-body {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}

#POD__Modal figure.zoom {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

#POD__Modal figure.zoom img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#POD__Modal figure.zoom img {
  transition: opacity .5s;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 
}
#POD__Modal figure {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}
<div class="modal fade" id="POD__Modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="POD__ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div id="modal__close" class="  sticky-top">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="POD__ModalLabel">Proof of delivery</h5>
            
            </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <figure class="zoom" onmousemove="zoom(event)" style="background-image: url(https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/70a2fd5f5acddd683b892245209974fa4c768498/324_0_1429_858/master/1429.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=e2b8991e17e7bd966a29f5c706fe2552)">
              <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/70a2fd5f5acddd683b892245209974fa4c768498/324_0_1429_858/master/1429.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=e2b8991e17e7bd966a29f5c706fe2552" />
            </figure>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





You should not put this close button as a direct child of the .modal element, but somewhere into the .modal-dialog element. That one is already relative positioned, so that it can serve as the reference point for the absolute positioning of descendant elements.

forget Bootstrap modal plugin and use only HTML5 <dialog> elements with their JS modal function. where you can use Bootstrap interface into them.

You can manipulate the default close button of the modal to be positioned there.
First, I moved your close button code inside the modal-header where close button is located by default.
Then added this css:
    #POD__Modal .btn-close {
        background-color: #00ff00;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-top: -60px;
        margin-right: -30px;
        opacity: 1;
    }

Then removed below codes since you no longer need them:
HTML:
<div id="modal__close" class="  sticky-top">
</div>

CSS:
#POD__Modal #modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: -0.1rem;
  right: 0rem;
  z-index: 999999;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

#POD__Modal .btn-close
{
  filter:  invert(1) grayscale(100%) brightness(300%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

Here is a working code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        /* POD Image Modal  */
        #POD__Modal .modal-body {
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #POD__Modal .modal-header {
            justify-content: space-around;
            color: var(--primary-color);
        }

        #POD__Modal .modal-content {
            border: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
            border-radius: 1rem;
        }

        #POD__Modal .modal-body {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
        }

        #POD__Modal figure.zoom {
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            cursor: zoom-in;
        }

        #POD__Modal figure.zoom img:hover {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        #POD__Modal figure.zoom img {
            transition: opacity .5s;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;

        }

        #POD__Modal figure {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
        }

        #POD__Modal .btn-close {
            background-color: #00ff00;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-top: -60px;
            margin-right: -30px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-5" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#POD__Modal">
        Show modal
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="POD__Modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="POD__ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="POD__ModalLabel">Proof of delivery</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <figure class="zoom" onmousemove="zoom(event)"
                        style="background-image: url(https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/70a2fd5f5acddd683b892245209974fa4c768498/324_0_1429_858/master/1429.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=e2b8991e17e7bd966a29f5c706fe2552)">
                        <img
                            src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/70a2fd5f5acddd683b892245209974fa4c768498/324_0_1429_858/master/1429.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=e2b8991e17e7bd966a29f5c706fe2552" />
                    </figure>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>



